# Multiple if statements, it deletes what is already in cells when if is not fulfilled

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get Excel to copy some values if the active sheet is a specific sheet. The problem I am having is that if the values from one sheet is transferred to the sheet it needs to be on, it overwrites the cells mentioned in the other if statements, but I need those values not to be overwritten. Can anybody help me solve this problem?

```
If ActiveSheet = Sheets("Parts for site") Then
    Sheets("INTERNAL").Cells(35, 4) = Sheets("Parts for site").Cells(i + 3 - n, 17)
    Else
End If

If ActiveSheet = Sheets("Parts for options") Then
    Sheets("INTERNAL").Cells(52, 4) = Sheets("Parts for options").Cells(i + 3 - n, 17)
    Else
End If

If ActiveSheet = Sheets("Parts for renovation") Then
    Sheets("EXTERNAL").Cells(29, 4) = Sheets("Parts for renovation").Cells(i + 2 - n, 17)
    Else
End If

If ActiveSheet = Sheets("Parts for site") Then
    Sheets("EXTERNAL").Cells(35, 4) = Sheets("Parts for site").Cells(i + 2 - n, 17)
    Else
End If

If ActiveSheet = Sheets("Parts for options") Then
    Sheets("EXTERNAL").Cells(52, 4) = Sheets("Parts for options").Cells(i + 2 - n, 17)
    Else
End If
```

Comment: Add `Exit Sub` in each of your `IF` statements.

Comment: Why do you have repeated tests for the same sheets?  You should be copying all required content withing a single If block...  And why are you copying different source cells to the same destination?

Comment: Can't you put all needed values in array? Then manipulate them how you want.

Comment: Following Tim's question, it seems you need to update your variables  `i` and/or `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the "&" to combine both values.

Here an example:

```
If ActiveSheet = Sheets("Parts for site") Then
    Sheets("INTERNAL").Cells(35, 4) = Sheets("INTERNAL").Cells(35, 4) & Sheets("Parts for site").Cells(i + 3 - n, 17)
    Else
End If
```

Comment: Simple solution, but it does not work, if i do this, then it will store both values in the same cell. I only need one value for each cell. i just need excel to differentiate between the sheets and add a specific value if it is a specific sheet without overwriting the other values.

Comment: Which cells exactly get overwritten? It looks like your destination is always different?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below:

```
Sub MySub()

Select Case ActiveSheet.Name

    Case "Parts for site"
        Sheets("INTERNAL").Cells(35, 4) = Sheets("INTERNAL").Cells(35, 4) & "||" & Sheets("Parts for site").Cells(i + 3 - n, 17)

    Case "Parts for options":
        Sheets("INTERNAL").Cells(52, 4) =  Sheets("INTERNAL").Cells(52, 4) & "||" & Sheets("Parts for options").Cells(i + 3 - n, 17)

    Case "Parts for renovation"
        Sheets("EXTERNAL").Cells(29, 4) = Sheets("EXTERNAL").Cells(29, 4) & "||" & Sheets("Parts for renovation").Cells(i + 2 - n, 17)

    Case "Parts for site"
        Sheets("EXTERNAL").Cells(35, 4) = Sheets("EXTERNAL").Cells(35, 4) &"||" & Sheets("Parts for site").Cells(i + 2 - n, 17)

    Case "Parts for options"
        Sheets("EXTERNAL").Cells(52, 4) = Sheets("EXTERNAL").Cells(52, 4) & "||" & Sheets("Parts for options").Cells(i + 2 - n, 17)

End If

End Sub
```

Is This you want, this will not clear the original values but will also have the old values too.